# Setting up jest, "test" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a very simple question.  I'm surprised this does not appear to be covered.

I'm trying to run `jest` in node v14 (non-module, server-side app).  Where is "test" function?  I used https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started but there is no import for "test" .. When I import jest, I see functions targeting running the tests but none to create the unit test itself.

```
> require('jest')
{
  SearchSource: [Getter],
  createTestScheduler: [Getter],
  getVersion: [Getter],
  run: [Getter],
  runCLI: [Getter]
}
```

```
$ jest

 FAIL  test/exhibit.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: test is not a function

      13 | test('mytest', async function() {
```

I assumed the `jest` script would have made `test` global, but it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: have you setup the test script in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import those. Just add this to your package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest ./",
}
```

Where `./` is the path to the up most folder with your tests

Then instead of running `jest` you run:

```
npm run test
```